# Question in population dynamics using exponential growth rate equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, applications, biology

Given population doubles in 20 minutes, what is intrinsic growth rate r?

Attempt: Given population doubles, using exponential growth rate we have $\frac{dN}{dt}=2N$ so $N(t)=N_0e^{2t}$ therefore r=2, but I have a feeling this is wrong since 20 minutes should be used somewhere around here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the population doubles in $20$ minutes, assuming your $t$ variable is in minutes, you should have that:

$$N(20) = 2N(0)$$

If you have an exponential growth rate by assumption, $\frac{dN}{dt} = \lambda N$, which results in $N = N_0e^{\lambda t}$.

If you evaluate this at times $t = 0$ and $t = 20$, you'll find that $N(0) = N_0$ and $N(20) = N_0e^{20\lambda}$. You can then plug in these expressions into the initial equation comparing the population at these two times to solve for $\lambda$, which should not be equal to $2$.

Comment: So I got $r=\frac{ln(2)}{20}$

Comment: That's correct; feel free to insert it into the original equation and confirm that the population at $t = 20$ minutes is indeed double that of the initial $t = 0$ population.